Set-CMTSStepConnectNetworkFolder and Set-CMTSStepApplyNetworkSetting error "Cannot access a disposed object"
"Cannot access a disposed object" is the error when running two commands in PowerShell to change the task sequences entries for an OSD.
For example: Run this command with the correct variables one after the other,
Set-CMTSStepConnectNetworkFolder and Set-CMTSStepConnectNetworkFolder the error is the results. The first command works but the 2nd one is the error results.
The order of the commands does not matter, but if they are ran in separated PowerShell window they work with no issues.
My thoughts are, the OSD needs to save the current setting. I have not been able to locate a command to save and then do the next command.
Thank you all in advance
